# How to display the details information from a particular table cell object?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a long hospital list in table view which is displayed using plist. Now my work is when I click any hospital in the table cell, there should display doctor's name, phone number and complete address of hospital in the next view. I have that particular doctor's name and hospital address in word document. So how to implement that. I think hardcode the hospitals details will be very painful as the list is too long. Is there any easy way??? please help me with code or any other effective links. Thanx in advance.....

Comment: please put your code , how you are showing data on table ...

Answer (score 0):

I'll try a general approach of your problem. You may try to get all of your hospital/doctor data in a XML file. Something like that may be :

```
<Hospitals>
    <Hospital name ="St John" doctorPhone="5554567" doctorName="Carter" hospitalAdresse="1 sq StJohn">
    </Hospital>

    <Hospital name ="St Peter" doctorPhone="5558901" doctorName="Grey" hospitalAdresse="1 sq StPeter">
    </Hospital>
<Hospitals>
```

You may parse this xml in your AppDelegate to have it ready when you start. You can look at seismic example that do quite the same thing.

Then you'll have a NSArray of Hospital. Each cell of your table should show the hospital that is t index : indexpath.row

With that when user touch a cell in your table view,with indexpath.row, you'll get the hospital infos. You can show them in another view or in a UIAlertView.

Anyway, you should give a look to Seismic example project that do something simillar to you

Good luck

Comment: Open XCode, go to the documentation and API reference. It opens help on all command and object of iphone API. Then search for seismic. You'll see the project in Sample Code